# Unable to launch Flutter app on AVD - java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, android-virtual-device

After taking a little brake from my flutter project I now decided to continue working on it.
However, upon attempting to launch the app on my AVD, I encountered the following error message:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:636)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (1).
```

Although the app was working fine a few weeks ago, I am seeking guidance on resolving this problem and making progress with my Flutter development. It appears to be a connectivity issue, specifically related to the `java.net.BindException`. I am uncertain about the root cause and how to rectify it.

Here is my `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3007], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.16.5 on channel stable at D:\Hobbys\Dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 78666c8dc5 (4 weeks ago), 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
    • Engine revision 3f3e560236
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\AppSolves\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✓] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.8.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.8.34330.188
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\AppSolves\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3007]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.217
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 120.0.2210.91

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

##### Approaches I have tried:

1. `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`
2. Restart both AVD and PC
3. Run `flutter upgrade --force`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fix

It appeared that my AVD had suddenly lost internet connection while booting.

##### I managed to fix it by following these steps:

1. Delete user data from AVD
2. Disable VPN
3. Cold boot